# Trocar a cor do input color

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Eu preciso de uma ajuda muito importante, tenho um input color com uma cor e um campo text.
Como eu poderia trocar a cor do input(color) usando o campo text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma resposta simples como a pergunta:

Nesse código o único que fiz foi atualizar o valor do `"input[type=color]"` usando os eventos `oncut`, `onkeyup`, ... do `HTMLInputElement`.

Eu adicionei algumas coisas extras.

```js
var hexColorInput = document.getElementById('hex_input'),
    colorSelector = document.getElementById('color_selector');

var updateHex ;

(updateHex = function () {
    hexColorInput.value = colorSelector.value;
})();

colorSelector.addEventListener('input', updateHex);

function updateSelector() {
    var val = hexColorInput.value;
    // adiciona o '#'
    if (val.charAt(0) !== '#') val = '#' + val;

    // expande uma cor desse tamanho: fff
    if (val.length === 4) {
        var red = val.charAt(1);
        red += red;
        var green = val.charAt(2);
        green += green;
        var blue = val.charAt(3);
        blue += blue;

        val = '#' + red + green + blue;
    }

    colorSelector.value = val;
}


['cut', 'keyup', 'paste'].forEach(function(evt) {
    hexColorInput.addEventListener(evt, updateSelector);
});
```

```html
<input id="color_selector" type="color"/>
<input id="hex_input" type="text">
```

Comment: Amigo....eu nunca pensaria nisso.......Estou trabalhando com funções simples baseadas no getElementById e value....

Comment: <input type="color" id="corUm" onchange="trocaCorUm();">
<input type="text" id="legendaCorUm" class="form-control">
////////JS:
function trocaCorUm(){document.getElementById("legendaCorUm").value=document.getElementById("corUm").value; }
////FIM JS
Esse trocar cor é para quando eu colocar a cor no input, exibir o cod #Hex no input text abaixo

Comment: @Victor Você está tentando me dizer algo?

Answer (score 2):

Esperando pelo evento `input` no campo de texto.

Basta pegar o valor da entrada de texto e aplicar como valor do campo de cor:

```js
(function(){

  var text  = document.querySelector('input[type=text]'),
      color = document.querySelector('input[type=color]');
  
  text.addEventListener('input', function(){
    color.value = this.value;
  });
  
})();
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='#RRGGBB'>
<input type='color'>
```

Comment: Como ativaria a função para executar o codigo ?

Comment: @Victor A função já está sendo executada

Comment: S mas n esta trocando o valor ?

Comment: @Victor Se você quiser que o valor do `"input[type=text]"` se atualize de acordo com o `"input[type=color]"` precisa adicionar um evento `"input"` para o `"input[type=color]"`, então atualizar o valor do `"input[type=text]"` com o valor do `"input[type=color]"` no escopo do evento. O evento `"input"` é, portanto, não suportado por navegadores velhos, mas cabe. Também é possível detectar se ele foi alterado com `requestAnimationFrame` e timers, algo serve de polyfill. Isso é como eu detectaria o evento `"input"`: `document.createElement('input').oninput === null`.